# Gulp : gulp-sass and gulp-css in default task one after the other

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-uglify

I'm having a problem with my comiled sass files not being picked for the minification with gulp-css in one command.

My gulpfile.js file is as follow:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    cssMin = require('gulp-css');

gulp.task('sass', function() {

    gulp.src('./scss/app.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/front'));

    gulp.src('./scss/wysiwyg.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/front'));

});

gulp.task('css', function() {

    gulp.src([
        './css/front/wysiwyg.css'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('wysiwyg.css'))
        .pipe(cssMin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));

    gulp.src([
        './css/admin/core.css',
        './js/plugin/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css',
        './css/admin/fileuploader.css',
        './js/plugin/imgareaselect-master/distfiles/css/imgareaselect-animated.css',
        './css/fa/css/font-awesome.css'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('app-admin.css'))
        .pipe(cssMin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));

    gulp.src([
        './css/front/animate.css',
        './bower_components/OwlCarousel2/src/css/owl.theme.default.css',
        './bower_components/OwlCarousel2/src/css/owl.autoheight.css',
        './bower_components/OwlCarousel2/src/css/owl.animate.css',
        './bower_components/OwlCarousel2/src/css/owl.carousel.css',
        './js/plugin/touchTouch/touchTouch.css',
        './css/fa/css/font-awesome.css',
        './css/front/app.css'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('app.css'))
        .pipe(cssMin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));

});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {

    gulp.src([
        './bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('modernizr.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));

    gulp.src([
        './bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        './js/plugin/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
        './js/plugin/jquery.easing.min.js',
        './js/plugin/mdn-bind.js',
        './js/plugin/jquery.cookie.js',
        './js/plugin/jquery.livequery.js',
        './js/plugin/preload/jquery.imgpreload.min.js',
        './js/plugin/jquery.tablednd.0.7.min.js',
        './js/plugin/jquery.tinysort.min.js',
        './js/plugin/uploader/fileuploader.min.js',
        './js/plugin/imgareaselect-master/jquery.imgareaselect.dev.js',
        './node_modules/jquery-datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('libs-admin.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));

    gulp.src([
        './js/object/systemObject.js',
        './js/object/formObject.js',
        './js/object/adminObject.js',
        './js/object/uploadObject.js',
        './js/object/dialogObject.js',
        './js/object/imageObject.js',
        './js/module/admin.js'
    ])
        .pipe(concat('app-admin.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));

    gulp.src([
        './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
        './node_modules/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
        './node_modules/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
        './bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        './js/plugin/touchTouch/touchCmd.jquery.js',
        './bower_components/OwlCarousel2/src/js/owl.carousel.js',
        './bower_components/OwlCarousel2/src/js/owl.autoplay.js',
        './bower_components/OwlCarousel2/src/js/owl.animate.js',
        './bower_components/OwlCarousel2/src/js/owl.navigation.js',
        './bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js',
        './bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.equalizer.js',
        './bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('libs.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));

    gulp.src([
        './js/angular/module.js',
        './js/angular/filters/**/*.js',
        './js/angular/services/**/*.js',
        './js/angular/directives/**/*.js',
        './js/angular/controllers/**/*.js',
        './js/object/Template.js',
        './js/module/front.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));

});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'css', 'scripts']);
```

Now, the problem is with the fact that I have to actually run the `gulp` command twice for the compiled sass file to be picked in the next round css minification.

Any idea how to do it so that it actually gets picked straight after it has been processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, your `sass`, `css`, and `scripts` are executed at the same time. Therefore your `css` task will minify the compiled sass that was there before the `sass` task was executed. The easiest way to resolve this, is to make the `sass` task a dependancy of the `css` task. This makes sure the `sass` task is executed before the `css` task.

Your `css` task would then look like this:

```
gulp.task('css', ['sass'], function {
   // your current body here
});
```

You can then remove the `sass` task from the `default` task, so that it looks like this:

```
gulp.task('default', ['css', 'scripts']);
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick - that's the one - found earlier today in the docs about the dependancy chaining.